# Shuffling a string containing 3 words, and assigning the output to three different strings

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, shuffle

I have a string, say

```
String unsorted = "A, B, C"
```

I would like to be able to randomly shuffle these, so eg the output would be "B, C, A" - I then need to be able to assign each to its own String.

It seems like I need to put into a ListArray, then Collections.shuffle, then pull the info out of the array again, and use something like

```
String[] sorted = unsorted.split(",");
String new1 = sorted[1]
String new2 = sorted[2]
String new3 = sorted[3]
```

Nothing I have tried seems to work, and I think I tried that many different ways I have no idea where I'm at anymore. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work with your approach?

Comment: 3 words or 3 characters?

Comment: One idea: first split, then shuffle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your strategy is correct. Try this:

```
List<String> words = Arrays.asList(unsorted.split(","));
Collections.shuffle(originalWords);
// After this you can access random-ed word
words.get(0); words.get(1);..
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
        String unsorted = "A, B, C";
        String[] sorted = unsorted.split(",");
        Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(sorted));
        String new1 = sorted[1];
        String new2 = sorted[2];
        String new3 = sorted[3];
```